# simple python else function won't run which would result in the end of of script

Tags: python

```
secret_word = "Michael Jackson"
guess = ""

guess = 0


guess_limit = 5

out_of_guesses = False


guess_count = 0




while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):


 if guess_count < guess_limit:


        guess = input("Enter Guess:")


        guess_count +=1


        print("Famous Pop Star")


        if guess_count < guess_limit:


            guess = input("Enter Guess:")


            guess_count += 1


            print("Died a legend")


            if guess_count < guess_limit:


                guess = input("Enter Guess:")


                guess_count += 1


                print("Very Talented")


                if guess_count < guess_limit:


                    guess = input("Enter Guess:")


                    guess_count += 1


                    print("Died in a bathtub")


                    if guess_count < guess_limit:


                        guess = input("Enter Guess:")


                        guess_count += 1


                        print("wore a plaid shirt" )


else:


    out_of_guesses = True





if out_of_guesses:


    print("You Lose....Answer was Michael Jackson")





else:


    print("You Win! Your knowledge over music is very vast!")
```

The Else functions at the very bottom simple won't run which would therefor decide if you won or lost the guessing game.

Comment: Is the `else` in your script really at the same indentation as the`while`?  That would keep it from ever being run.

Comment: But why not just define your loop against the number of guesses directly?  Also any particular reason for nesting all the `if` statements?

Comment: Please clean up your formatting. You don't need blank lines between every line of code, which makes it unnecessarily difficult to read

Comment: I only added the spaces because they wouldn't let me ask this question unless I added spaces. Also what is nesting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you have learnt about `python indent` or not, but as @JonathanK said, you got problem about `if else`, and actually your code is wrong now. This is my suggest code, hope it get your purpose:

```py
secret_word = "Michael Jackson"
guess = ""
# guess = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False
guess_count = 0

while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):

    guess = input("Enter Guess:")
    if guess_count < guess_limit and guess != secret_word:
        guess_count +=1
        print("Famous Pop Star")

        guess = input("Enter Guess:")
        if guess_count < guess_limit and guess != secret_word:
            guess_count += 1
            print("Died a legend")

            guess = input("Enter Guess:")
            if guess_count < guess_limit and guess != secret_word:
                guess_count += 1
                print("Very Talented")

                guess = input("Enter Guess:")
                if guess_count < guess_limit and guess != secret_word:
                    guess_count += 1
                    print("Died in a bathtub")

                    guess = input("Enter Guess:")
                    if guess_count < guess_limit and guess != secret_word:
                        guess_count += 1
                        print("wore a plaid shirt" )

                    else:
                        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("You Lose....Answer was Michael Jackson")

else:
    print("You Win! Your knowledge over music is very vast!")
```